# Google Cardboard Can't Call onNewFrame

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I just bought a Google Cardboard Viewer and decided to take a shot at making an app. I have played around with OpenGL and have no problem with the basics of that.
I created a new project following the source from the only sample I could find "Treasure Hunt" linked to from the "Getting Started" for Cardboard.

I can run my own test application and the Treasure Hunt sample application from Google on my Nexus 7 tablet, but I get an error on my phone:

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardView$StereoRenderer.onNewFrame(com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.HeadTransform) on instance of my.app.cardboardtest.CardboardRenderer

Since I get the same error from the sample from Google, I don't think I need to share any of my code specifically. This is a link to their code:

https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java

I have a T-Mobile Galaxy Note 3 running Android 5.0
Is this the final tipping point for me to upgrade my phone? lol

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with your build in Android Studio.
Try moving the cardboard.jar file (that contains the vrtoolkit.so binary) to a folder called /lib and point to it.

Upshot is, android cannot find vrtoolkit.so in the delployed apk. The binary is a new addition to the jar, and the docs are older than that.

Or, just stick with Eclipse until Studio is a little more rattled in.
Just a headsup the learning curves around VR development are turbulent like the event horizon of a black hole ...

[image: blackhole]

Comment: Do you mean app/libs directory? Because jar files are usually included there. I did have it there and did the whole right-click 'Add as library' and then made sure my build.gradle was including the libs directory. I'll give it a go adding it to an app/lib directory in case that is what you meant for me to do.

Comment: I tried redownloading the cardboard.jar file and putting it in the /lib directory instead of the /libs directory and nothing changed.

It's just strange that I can download apps meant for Cardboard from the Play store and they run. But the sample code Google gave and their demos on the Cardboard app don't run

Comment: I use eclipse, not studio. I also remove the binary from cardboard.jar, since I write my own renderers. Again your issue is the docs are for a pre-binary version of cardboard, and also for eclipse. You might try the VR dev google+ group for some direction with Studio.

Comment: I used to use Eclipse, but I thought I should move to Android Studio. I created a project from the git source Google gives and it doesn't even compile. lol. First it doesn't import the src .java files correctly. Then it gives me an error "RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo..."

Comment: Maybe I should also note that it says "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 'com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt.MainActivity' on path: DexPathList[[zip file '/data/app/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.tresurehunt-1/base.apk'],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]"